# Oracle Reports UTF8 PDF fields trimmed to half the number of characters

Tags: oracle, pdf, report, utf, truncation

Can you please help with this issue I'm having after the introduction of UTF8 on the Reports servers:
We had up to now: database - UTF8, reports server - CL8ISO8859P5.
Now the reporting server was changed to UTF8 too and in PDF fields which display characters with multi-byte code points are treated as they would have half of their real length.
They are filled only to half their length, the rest of the text is trimmed and the remainder of the field is left blank.
If I enlarge the field in Reports Builder, the text inside will accomodate more characters, proportionately, but also still up to only about half.

I've tried recompiling the reports (with UTF8 set in the compiler), tried also specifying NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=CHAR in both DB and application server, also changing other fonts, all with no effect.

However, if we put in the respective DB field regular characters, with code points <= 255, and maintaining the same settings everywhere, the fields are filled entirely.
.
The fonts used are true type and subset-ed into the pdf (for example Courier New or Times New Roman) - same as before the UTF8 change.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated, thank you!